# Oracle SQL - Subquery to get the employees that receive more than the Max_Salary for their Job_Id

Tags: oracle, subquery

In HR Schema, we have a table jobs, with min and max salary for each job id. I have to find the employees that receive more than the Max_Salary for their Job_Id, using subquery.

I have tried to make this subquery, but I'm getting "no data found".

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME,SALARY, JOB_ID FROM HR.EMPLOYEES E WHERE SALARY >(SELECT MAX_SALARY  FROM HR.JOBS J WHERE E.JOB_ID = J.JOB_ID );
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your query looks OK. It seems like there are no employees that satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH SALARY_DETAIL AS (SELECT JOB_ID, MAX(MAX_SALARY) AS MAX_SALARY  FROM JOBS J GROUP BY J.JOB_ID)
 
SELECT E.FIRST_NAME, E.SALARY, E.JOB_ID FROM HR.EMPLOYEES E , SALARY_DETAIL S 
  WHERE S.JOB_ID = E.JOB_ID 
        AND E.SALARY > S.MAX_SALAR
```